Does Bangladesh have something like Posse Comitatus Act?
I'm curious what's behind the reported Bangladesh army refusal to shoot protesters (unlike the police there). BTW, the government had declared an "indefinite nationwide curfew" a couple of days ago, which presumably was giving security forces extra power to prevent gatherings. And the army then urged people to obey it.
Does Bangladesh have something like Posse Comitatus Act?

It seems like Bangladesh is in the middle of some possible government overthrow and mabye the army is not willing to side with the current government.

This seems two entirely separate questions. Firstly why soldiers took actions that may or may not be illegal (refusing to obey orders), and secondly about the Posse Comitatus Act. And I guess thirdly whether there was any other legal basis for refusing to shoot protestors.

@StuartF: you're welcome to ask the other questions you have in mind.

@MakeStackExchangeGREAT4ever, let me know if you need me to add more information to my answer.

Reuters Exclusive: Bangladesh army refused to suppress protest, sealing Hasina's fate covers exactly this:

The night before long-time leader Sheikh Hasina abruptly fled Bangladesh amid deadly protests, her army chief (note: Gen. Waker-uz-Zaman) held a meeting with his generals and decided that troops would not open fire on civilians to enforce a curfew, two serving army officers with knowledge of the discussions told Reuters.


Zaman has not publicly explained his decision to withdraw support from Hasina. But the scale of the protests and a death toll of at least 241 made supporting Hasina at all costs untenable, three former senior Bangladesh army officers told Reuters.

Most democratic countries both have a notion of martial law and a  (possibly ill-defined, but very real), aversion to seeing it employed to deal with political domestic events.  They may also have laws akin to Posse Comitatus,  (for example: Germany article 35 )  but I wouldn't consider such a law a requirement for Bangladesh-style loss of military support when armed forces need to choose between that and mass killings of civilians.
Dictators always need to watch their back in this regard and the successful ones do it well.  You can search for "...some dictator... loss support military" and see numerous cases of the ones that have failed:
Haiti, Baby Doc
Romania, Ceaucescu
Phillippines, Marcos
Ukraine, 2014

The Armed Forces' deputy chief of staff, Lieutenant-General Yuri Dumansky, resigned because he disagreed with the involvement of the army in the conflict.[184] "Today the army is being involved in the civil conflict, which could lead to the mass deaths of civilians and soldiers," he said.[185]

Even now, some are hoping the Venezuelan military will withdraw support for Maduro.  That may not happen as long as the death toll remains low, and as long as party thugs can suppress the protesters on their own, but if they lose that level of control and the army has to shoot widely, all bets are off.  In Maduro's case however, we need to remember Chavez was military himself.
Interestingly considering Tianamen,   the PLA is under the direct control of the CCP itself.

The PLA is not a traditional nation-state military. It is a part, and the armed wing, of the CCP and controlled by the party, not by the state.

Another thing to consider is that laws and constitutions are one thing, the actual practice and customs of the national polity is another.  The Soviet Constitution of 1936 had all sorts of freedoms guaranteed in it... (see article 125 for a good laugh).
Contextually relevant: the Bangladeshi military has been fairly coup-happy in the past.  And has previously run the country under martial law.
p.s. I am unsure why a US-specific law needs to be brought up in the context of Bangladesh, for the reasons mentioned in the comments.

Fair point that this may be an unwritten 'law' to a good extent and dependant on who runs the army and how much they're willing to support the government, whatever the toll.

"why a US-specific law needs to be brought up in the case of Bangladesh" Because it used the regular army to enforce domestic laws something that is illegal in the U.S. and it isn't obvious how widespread bans on using a country's army to do so are in the world.

@ohwilleke Would a question leading with "Does Bangladesh having something like Article 35?" (German Basic Law pertaining to this type of stuff) be perceived as very clear by US citizens?  I suspect not.  But  I did move to a p.s. to lessen its prominence in my answer.

"Article 35" doesn't have wikipedia article tho', at least not in English. If you're gonna complain about "Americentrism" in the Q, you should perhaps consider that angle. Is it even the right article # 35? http://hrlibrary.umn.edu/research/germany-constitution.html

It seems to allow German AF to be used in some kind of emergencies (natural disasters etc.) but does not explicitly prohibit their other [internal] uses.

Article 87a (2) "Apart from defence, the Armed Forces may be employed only to the extent expressly permitted by this Basic Law." is probably the more pertinent one.

No, the Bangladesh constitution (Ref. 6) doesn't prohibit the Government from calling upon the military to assist it to maintain law and order, and enforce law, during peacetime. (In fact, in my opinion, I think the US is an exception having this kind of law as most countries do not have an equivalent to it).
As for why the Bangladesh army refused to assist the government to control political protests it is hard to gauge the truth of the matter. The former Prime Minister Ms. Sheikh Hasina's government did go overboard with the brutal use of force to suppress political protests:

Sheikh Hasina's government reacted with overwhelmingly excessive force against students, and police opened fire on protesters with live rounds, killing more than 400 people in the span of 23 days ... More than 11,000 people were arrested in just two weeks ... Violence shook the nation; the death toll kept climbing to nearly 100 people—the highest and deadliest ever for a single-day protest in the nation's history. Public anger only mounted; student protesters called for a "March to Dhaka" on August 5. In response, hundreds of thousands took to the streets in Dhaka and other surrounding towns ready to converge on Shahbag.
That was when the law enforcers realised the situation was beyond salvation and counselled Sheikh Hasina to leave. Initially, she reportedly refused and urged for using even more force to subdue the crowd. The army refused. (Ref. 1)

But, given the history of the Bangladesh Army in interfering in politics, and even overthrowing elected representatives to capture power and govern, it is hard to buy the argument that the army chief was being conscientious. We also cannot ascertain the truth behind the Army chiefs claim that the government ordered the army to shoot the civilians, and "he refused". It is a fact that with Ms. Sheik Hasina's ouster, the Bangladesh Army has stepped into the political vacuum and has captured powered there. It is currently dictating the formation of the new caretaker government. There is nothing democratic about it.
Interestingly, Ms. Sheik Hasina was denied the chance to give a public speech before she left the country.
Excerpts of this speech, that she has since shared with her party members, has been published in the Indian media, and in it she claims she resigned because she didn't want to violently deal with the protestors:

“I resigned, so that I did not have to see the procession of dead bodies. They wanted to come to power over the dead bodies of students, but I did not allow it, I resigned from premiership. I could have remained in power if I had surrendered the sovereignty of Saint Martin Island and allowed America to hold sway over the Bay of Bengal. I beseech to the people of my land, 'Please do not be manipulated by radicals.”
“If I had remained in the country, more lives would have been lost, more resources would have been destroyed. I made the extremely difficult decision to exit. I became your leader because you chose me, you were my strength,” Hasina emphasised.
... “I would like to repeat to the young students of Bangladesh. I have never called you Razakars. Rather My words were distorted to incite you. I request you to watch the full video of that day. Conspirators have taken advantage of innocence and used you to destabilise the nation.”
Before the quota movement Hasina in April had told parliament that America is pursuing a strategy of regime change in her country. “They are trying to eliminate democracy and introduce a government that will not have a democratic existence.” (Ref. 2)

The accusation of the role of the American Government in Ms. Hasina's ouster further muddies the matter, as, historically the Bangladesh Army has often depended on the support of the United States to suppress democracy in Bangladesh and rule the country.
(Note: To add to the confusion, Ms. Sheik Hasina's son has refuted that his mother has made any such statement. It isn't clear if this is damage control by him as his mother has been vocal with her hostility to the US (Ref. 3) because of the role they played in her family's massacre and the genocide of Bengalis (Ref. 4, 5), and the political demands they made on her that she perceived as impeaching on Bangladesh's sovereignty.)
Sources:

Why can’t India accept that the people of Bangladesh toppled Sheikh Hasina?

Sheikh Hasina alleges US role in ouster, says could've remained in power if she surrendered sovereignty of Saint Martin Island

The Bad Blood Between Sheikh Hasina and the US

The Genocide the U.S. Can’t Remember, But Bangladesh Can’t Forget

How the US envoy exposed genocide in East Pakistan

Bangladesh Constitution 1972 (reinst. 1986, rev. 2014) 



"historically the Bangladesh Army has often depended on the support of the United States to suppress democracy in Bangladesh". Perhaps, but ref 3 also says: "On December 10, 2021, the U.S. Treasury Department imposed sanctions on the Rapid Action Battalion (RAB) and several of its former officials. [...] On May 21 of this year, the U.S. State Department enacted visa restrictions on former Bangladesh army chief Gen. (Retd) Aziz Ahmed, accusing him of “involvement in significant corruption” and “undermining… Bangladesh’s democratic institutions.”"

Are the US pressure tactics aimed at strengthening democracy or securing concessions from the present regime in Bangladesh?: Despite sanctions and other pressure from foreign governments, Hasina has refused to budge from her position on several issues. She has refused to sign agreements such as the Acquisition and Cross-Servicing Agreement (ACSA) and the General Security of Military Information Agreement (GSOMIA). The west today would be painting her as the bastion of democracy if she allied with US.

Yeah, that and the rumour that the US wanted an island (Saint Martin’s) for a base. Which despite categorical denial by the US, an Indian newspaper concludes is true based on ???

It's true though that the US has boosted their foreign financial assistance to some countries in the region, e.g. to Nepal (by a factor of 4 or so) no doubt trying to counter China's as among the objectives. (I love the Chinese expression that the US is trying to "kidnap" Nepal.) https://www.stimson.org/2024/emerging-great-game-china-india-america-engagement/ Whether that US move is also indented to "dominate India" as the [Indian] tinfoil hats would have it, YMMV.

And yeah, no public offer was made to Dhaka to join the Quad, but the Indian  press claims that also happened (perhaps because the Chinese appeared to say so).

@timetakesitstoll Ms. Hasina and her political allies have publicly made the claims that the west is interested in a military base in BD. It is obvious that Bangladesh offers a huge geostrategic advantage to Quad, and only the naive will believe that the US hasn't held any talk with it on it. Quad does have an economic and connectivity aspect that Bangladesh is very much interested in, but they are averse to the military aspect of it.

I'm not saying these categorically don't exist. I'm just saying all [categorical] claims to their existence seem to come from Indian or Chinese who feel 'elbowed out' from Bangladesh. And while many Indian and Chinese sources harp on that, it seems to me many Bangladeshis aren't too happy with their closer neighbors https://asia.nikkei.com/Economy/Bangladeshi-India-out-campaign-hits-Ramadan-sales

@timetakesitstoll These claims are not new and were being made by Ms. Hasina (and her local allies) when she was in power, long before she was ousted. Multiple sources - Bangladesh, China and India - since corroborate the claim which makes it more credible, even if they have their own political self-interest to do so (moreover, these public postures are also meant to sent a clear diplomatic message to the US where these countries stand on the particular issue). (I agree though it isn't credulous to relate this to Ms. Hasina's ouster - It remains to be seen if it is China or US that benefits).


Does Bangladesh have something like the Posse Comitatus Act?

No.

I'm curious what's behind the reported Bangladesh army refusal to shoot protesters (unlike the police there).

Short answer
a. The Army was scared of losing its quota in UN peacekeeping missions
b. The Army Chief wanted to keep himself away from political termoil because of the salty experience of one of his predecessors
Long answer
a. The UN peacekeeping missions
Like other countries in South Asia, Bangladesh's armed forces are not paid well enough. UN peacekeeping missions are one of the most popular ways for armed forces personnel to earn a significant amount of money.
Sheikh Hasina's regime was able to create a faction in the armed forces where she provided them promotions on political and napotistic considerations and engaged them in illegal tasks like enforced disappearances, extrajudicial killings, extorsion, etc.
In the beginning, these illegal activities were hidden from the UN. However, because of investigative reports from some news agencies like Netra News, Al Jazeera, DW, etc.; NGOs like Adhikar, etc.; exiled personnel like Jukernine Saer Khan, Tasneem Khalil, etc.; social media influencers like Elias Hossen, Pinaki Bhattachaya, Dr. Taj Hashmi, Shahed Alam, Zahed Ur Rahman, etc.; victims and families of victims, etc., these illegal acts of the Sheikh Hasina regime came out.



The following screenshot says that the then information minister, Junaid Ahmed Palak, handed over the names of fifty individuals who were spreading "rumors" from abroad to Facebook so that they could take down their accounts, etc.



As a result, the UN started to ask questions about the armed forces personnel's ethical and moral legitimacy in participating in UN peacekeeping missions. As a result, the Army Chief decided not to take any responsibility for the Sheikh Hasina regime's illegal and criminal enterprise.
Please note that the Army Chief met with heavy pressure from Sheikh Hasina's pet officers (social media disclosed that there were nine such high-ranking officers). However, because of the students' uprising and because of Sheikh Hasina's flight to India, the Army Chief was finally able to suppress them.



b. The past salty experience
The Bangladesh Army, as an institution, had two major salty experiences since 2006.

The subjugation of Gen. Moin U. Ahmed (by the Indian government)

For deatils, check this link: What are the reasons behind a strong anti-India sentiment in Bangladesh?

The BDR Massacre

Allegedly, the Indian government facilitated it.



